# Outbound Email Mailer Service throwing error "Stored procedure failed: SP_MAILINGS_SAVE_LINKURLS"

Tags: 2013-sp1, outbound-email

We are using SDL tridion 2013 SP1 .The outbound email mailer service doing something wrong it is keep logging below error in log file . we did check in outbound email database inside table "Queued_Emails" there are few emails which are not getting deleted and may be cause of this error below is detailed error

```
Stored procedure failed: SP_MAILINGS_SAVE_LINKURLS
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.DataSession.OpenRecordsetByStoredProcedure(UserContext userContext, String sProcName, Dictionary`2 parameters, Dictionary`2 outputParameters, Int32 timeoutSeconds)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.MailingDal.SaveLinkUrls(TcmUri mailingURI, EmailLinkUrls linkUrls)
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.MailerBatches.FetchedMessage.UpdateTmsLinksInRenderdContent()
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.MailerBatches.FetchedMessage.PreProcessMessage()
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.MailerBatches.FetchedTestMessage.PreProcessMessage()
   at Tridion.OutboundEmail.Services.Mailer.OutboundEmailMailer.HandleTestMessages(Dictionary`2 messages)
2016-08-18T15:28:37 [Error] ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SH_OEDB"."EMAIL_LINKURL"."EMAIL_LINK_URL")
ORA-06512: at "SH_OEDB.MAILINGS_SAVE_LINKURLS", line 22
ORA-06512: at line 1
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleErrorHelper(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, String procedure, Boolean bCheck, Int32 isRecoverable)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException.HandleError(Int32 errCode, OracleConnection conn, String procedure, IntPtr opsErrCtx, OpoSqlValCtx* pOpoSqlValCtx, Object src, Boolean bCheck)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requery, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.DataSession.OpenRecordsetByStoredProcedure(UserContext userContext, String sProcName, Dictionary`2 parameters, Dictionary`2 outputParameters, Int32 timeoutSeconds)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it's trying to save an empty URL for a tracked link. That is not allowed. I would check your template for any empty links and fix them. That includes ones you're explicitly tracking (i.e. using GetLinkTrackingURL) and implicitly (by enabling the option to track all links on the Post-processing TBB)

Comment: Thanks Peter We are able to fix the problem after updating empty URL with valid one using this oracle Update Command                                               UPDATE QUEUED_EMAILS_MESSAGES SET MESSAGE= REPLACE(MESSAGE, '*__Link__ url=''''', '*__Link__ url=''https://www.test.com.kw''');